# Isinstance slice in Numba jitclass __getitem__

Tags: python, slice, numba, isinstance

I am using a [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) `jitclass` and would like to make a transformation on the key whenever it is not a slice (but I want to keep the slice functionality).

**Question:** How can I?

*To give a little context, I would rather write `tensor[coord]` than `tensor[tensor_to_formalseries(coord, tensor.dim)]` and I also like the condensed `tensor[:key]` more than `tensor.formal_series[:key]`.*

Below are 3 examples that work in pure python and don't as jitclasses.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
from numba.experimental import jitclass
from numba.core.types import int64, SliceType

@njit
def tensor_to_formalseries(coordinate: int, dim=2):
    key = coordinate * 2 # some crazy stuff with coordinate
    return key
```

```
@jitclass(spec={"formal_series": int64[:], "dim": int64})
class Tensor1:
    def __init__(self, dim=2):
        self.dim = dim
        self.formal_series = np.arange(10)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, (slice, SliceType)):
            # tried with SliceLiteral, slice2_type, slice3_type from numba.core.types
            print("key is a slice")
            return self.formal_series[key]
        else:
            print("key is not a slice")
            return self.formal_series[tensor_to_formalseries(key, self.dim)]

tensor = Tensor1()
print(tensor[:3])
print(tensor[2])
"""
Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
  NumbaTypeError: isinstance() does not support variables of type "slice<a:b>".
"""
```

```
@jitclass(spec={"formal_series": int64[:], "dim": int64})
class Tensor2:
    def __init__(self, dim=2):
        self.dim = dim
        self.formal_series = np.arange(10)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(self.formal_series[key], np.ndarray):
            print("key is a slice")
            return self.formal_series[key]
        else:
            print("key is not a slice")
            return self.formal_series[tensor_to_formalseries(key, self.dim)]

tensor = Tensor2()
print(tensor[:3])
print(tensor[2])
"""
Use of unsupported NumPy function 'numpy.ndarray' or unsupported use of the function.
"""
```

```
@jitclass(spec={"formal_series": int64[:], "dim": int64})
class Tensor3:
    def __init__(self, dim=2):
        self.dim = dim
        self.formal_series = np.arange(10)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            len(self.formal_series[key])
            print("key is a slice")
            return self.formal_series[key]
        except Exception:
            # should be a TypeError, but jitclass doesn't like it: UnsupportedError: Exception matching is limited to <class 'Exception'>
            print("key is not a slice")
            return self.formal_series[tensor_to_formalseries(key, self.dim)]

tensor = Tensor3()
print(tensor[:3])
"""
Overload of function 'mul': File: <numerous>: Line N/A.
  With argument(s): '(slice<a:b>, int64)':
"""

print(tensor[2])
"""
Overload of function 'len': File: <numerous>: Line N/A.
  With argument(s): '(int64)':
 No match.
"""
```

Answer (score 1):

As of numba 0.56, `isinstance()` is not supported inside a numba class. Source: [numba jitclass documentation](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/jitclass.html)

Is it really needed to numba compile the "is this a slice" check? Most likely your code spent the most time on the transformation part, which means that the transformation part is where you need to focus your optimisation efforts.

What i would do, is to detect the type of the key with regular python code, then use a njit compiled numba function to do the actual transformation.

I would also refrain from using the experimental numba class type. You are probably better off using a regular python class that simply calls a numba compiled function.

Comment: I am using `isinstance` inside the jitclass (on primitive types as well as the jitclass instance itself) and it does work as intended, this is why I thought there could be something done.

Well, `transformation()` is just a simplification of the actual function that takes a coordinate in tensor space and returns the position in the respective formal series space. So yes, I could define a new method that does that specifically, but I would lose the "bracket" notation that is so much nicer.

I need to use my class in a njit environment, so a regular python class won't suffice.

Comment: @Louis-Amand Why do you **need** to use the class in a njit environment? The njit environment is only helpful if it gives you better perfomance, so why not do certain things outside of the njit environment if better performance is not necessary?

Comment: @Louis-Amand you could also try to code it without using a class at all, that might be easier

Comment: I am doing minimizations and Euler schemes and there is a very clear need (~x50 speedup) for a njit environment. Moreover it is **much** easier to work with the classes for many operations on tensors can be simplified in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Evidently you can pass slices into numba functions and use them as you would a regular slice, you just can't ask if an object is a slice. A pretty hacky way to get around this is to first use the slice on an array, then evaluate the output. For your application, I assume that you really only are checking whether the input is a slice or an int. In this case you can use this code

```py
@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def _checkifslice(obj, maxsize=100):
    array = np.zeros(maxsize)
    test = array[obj]
    if len(np.shape(test)) == 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Typically, if you are using this within a class, then you can pick an optimal `maxsize` based on the attributes of the class.

Clearly this isn't the most optimal solution, but it is a workaround until numba makes slices easier to work.